# Stack Exchange account and Data Explorer accounts are separate - can I join them?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

For some strange reason, when I log in to data.stackexchange.com I get some generated john-doe username, as opposed to my actual username on all other network sites - using the same OpenID URL.

Is that my fault, or an issue with the difference between data.stackexchange.com and normal Q&A sites? And can I 'join' these accounts together somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the Data Explorer (data.stackexchange.com) is a completely separate system that cannot be linked to Q&A site profiles.

You're welcome to edit your DE profile, though, to set whatever display name you wish to use.

Comment: Well, I tried using my SX username, and got an error about it being taken (i.e. non-unique username).

Comment: @einpoklum Huh. Didn't realize they were required to be unique. Ah well. Looks like you had a DE account before and it's still around. You can't log into it anymore, though, since it was created with myopenid and that service doesn't exist anymore. I changed the display name on it, so it should free it up for your current account.